# Grok filter not working even though it works in grok debugger

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok

I'm using logstash-1.4.0 with elasticsearch 1.3.4 and kibana 3.1.1 (I know I'm outdated, that's the best I can do right now).

**Log Example:**

> 2016-05-31 16:05:33 RequestManager [INFO] The manual flag LOLROFLin TRALALA 123456Was changed to true

**My grok filter:**

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:clazz} %{NOTSPACE:level} %{GREEDYDATA:content}"}
    }

    if (!([stack_trace])) and (!([clazz] == "RequestAsset")) {
        drop {}
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why do I not see the grok fields in kibana? I only see the default fields but not mine. Grok Debugger shows success, but kibana does not work.
2. My goal is to drop any log message that does not have a stack trace OR is not from class (called clazz in my grok filter) "RequestAsset". Should this work? can I use the fields created by the grok filter in a seperate if filter?

EDIT: I realised what went wrong, I was using the log4j plugin which already seperates the log to its contents, and the field message was already just the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your grok filter in this [grok debugger](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match) and it failed. So i have rewritten it.

Here is the correct grok filter.

```
filter {
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:clazz} %{NOTSPACE:level} %{GREEDYDATA:content}"}
}

if (!([stack_trace])) and (!([clazz] == "RequestAsset")) {
    drop {}
}
```

TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 => `%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?`

If you see "_grokparsefailure" in Kibana, you know that your grok filter failed.

On your second question shouldn't you use the OR operator?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two? I also tried them both in the grok debugger you mentioned but both did not work. I used this one and both do work: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I'm sorry i pasted the wrong grok statement. You should check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I realised what went wrong, I was using the log4j plugin which already seperates the log to its contents, and the field message was already just the message itself.